# Use Fourier series of $f(x)=x(\pi-|x|)$ in $(-\pi,\pi)$ to compute the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-1)^3}.$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The fourier series I obtained was

$$x(\pi-|x|)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}+1}{n^3}\sin(nx),\tag1$$

which I checked is correct by plotting RHS and LHS. I'm not sure what to set $x$ as when evaluating the RHS, since I often get $0$ due to the sine.

I'm also having trouble converting the denominator in the sum fom $n^3$ to $(2n-1)^3$.

Some have noted that my Fourier expansion is wrong. I'm not sure about its correctness but based on the plots on Maple, it seems correct. The blue is the original function and the red is the Fourier series.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: Your series can't be right, since $x=\pi/2$ in your series would give a nice closed form for $\zeta(3)$ (and this is not available)

Comment: @CalvinKhor $x=\pi/2$ does not produce a closed-form for $\zeta(3)$ but rather for $\beta(3)$ which is the question all about. However, the value is wrong anyway.

Comment: @mrtaurho oh, yes of course

Comment: @CalvinKhor - Please see my edit. I forgot the $+1$ in the numerator. Typo.

Comment: @Parseval yes, after you have edited the fourier series, now it looks better...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you got the right expansion, it is not difficult at all. Choose $x=\pi/2$ which leads to the following

\begin{align*}
\frac\pi2\left(\pi-\left|\frac\pi2\right|\right)&=\frac4\pi\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}+1}{n^3}\sin\left(n\frac\pi2\right)\\
\frac{\pi^3}{16}&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}+1}{n^3}\sin\left(n\frac\pi2\right)
\end{align*}

Now we can distinguish between even and odd $n$. For even $n$ the term $\sin(n\pi/2)$ will be $0$ and therefore these sum terms cancel, whereas for odd $n$ the value will alternate between $-1$ and $1$ (and equal $(-1)^n$ for odd and even $n$ in the new index). So we can further conclude that

\begin{align*}
\frac{\pi^3}{16}&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}+1}{n^3}\sin\left(n\frac\pi2\right)\\
&=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^{(2n+1)+1}+1}{(2n+1)^3}(-1)^n\\
&=2\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-1)^3}
\end{align*}

> $$\therefore~\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-1)^3}~=~\frac{\pi^3}{32}$$

Note that the here-occuring sum is a particular case of the [Dirichlet Beta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletBetaFunction.html) $\beta(s)$; precisely we just managed to show that $\beta(3)={\pi^3}/{32}$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your effort!

Comment: @Parseval No problem, happy to help!

Comment: Why did you change the index from $0$ to $1$ again for the $n?$ And also, for $n=1$ we have $\sin(\pi/2)=1\neq (-1)^1 = -1.$

Comment: @Parseval The latter index change is only to exactly match the given sum which starts with $n=1$ too. Of course, for $n=1$ we got $1$ therefore within the second sum we start with the term $\frac{(-1)^0}{(2\cdot 0+1)^3}=1$, moreover for $n=3$, i.e. the next important value, we got that $\sin\left(3\frac\pi2\right)=-1$ and also $\frac{(-1)^1}{(2\cdot 1+1)^3}=-\frac1{3^3}$. Are these proper answers to your questions or am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, I see now what you have done. Sorry just silly thinking by me.

Answer (score 1):

A hint to get you started -

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty ((-1)^{n+1} +1 )a_n =2a_1 + 0 + 2a_3+0 + \dots = 2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k-1}  $$

and then the choice $x=\pi/2$ should allow you to conclude.

Comment: I understand! Well explained.